# How to pass a parameter with space in nohup?

Tags: shell-script

I have script to run a jar, like shown below.

```
user="Tim Tom";
jarfile=./app.jar
SC_CD="java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -DUSER='$user' $jarfile"
nohup $SC_CD
```

And im geeting error message as

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile Tom
```

So, my understanding is, it is taking the word after space as jar name.

Therefore, my question is,
**How to pass param with space in it?**

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Do you need to store the command in a variable?  Could you just `nohup java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -DUSER="$user" "$jarfile"` instead of having those on different lines?

Comment: I agree fully with @EricRenouf; you would be much better off without stuffing your arguments into a parameter.  Any workaround is going to be error-prone and, without *excellent* shell scripting skills, hard to debug.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't mind reducing the portability of your product by depending on `bash` instead of `/bin/sh`, you could use `bash` arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on Eric Renouf's comments on previous iteration of this answer on how `nohup`and `bash` conspire to thwart escaping spaces

```
user="Tim Toms"
jarfile=./app.jar
SC_CD="java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -DUSER='$user' $jarfile"
echo $SC_CD  > temp.sh
nohup bash temp.sh
```

If the point was to let that java run in the background, I might have just done something like

`echo java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -DUSER=\'$user\' $jarfile | at now`

and forgotten about `nohup`  (so what if maybe there's some trash email to clean up)

==== old answer below, just so comments make sense.  Forget below otherwise ====

While it seems your statements actually do call `nohup` with "Tim Tom" in single quotes, perhaps `nohup` does its `system()` call with a simple string instead of making an `exec` call, and making the string loses the quotes.

I just tested by putting an `echo` in front of the `nohup`

I am not really in a position to test it, but I suggest try making your first line into

`user='"Tim Tom"'`

as single quotes are supposed to prevent expansion and should pass the double quotes on to `nohup`

I'm basing this on making a test script like

```
ser="Tim Tom";
jarfile=./app.jar
SC_CD="java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -DUSER='$user' $jarfile"
echo nohup $SC_CD
```

then when I `sh -x test.sh` I get

```
+ user='Tim Tom'
+ jarfile=./app.jar
+ SC_CD='java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -DUSER='\''Tim Tom'\'' ./app.jar'
+ echo nohup java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m '-DUSER='\''Tim' 'Tom'\''' ./app.jar
nohup java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -DUSER='Tim Tom' ./app.jar
```

But making the suggested change gives

```
+ user='"Tim Tom"'
+ jarfile=./app.jar
+ SC_CD='java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -DUSER='\''"Tim Tom"'\'' ./app.jar'
+ echo nohup java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m '-DUSER='\''"Tim' 'Tom"'\''' ./app.jar
nohup java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -DUSER='"Tim Tom"' ./app.jar
```

Note that in both cases, echo shows that nohup should be getting at least the first level of quotes in its arguments.  That's why I am suggesting adding an additional level

Comment: That won't help here because the quotes inside the variable are just other characters in the string, they're not being syntactic to affect word splitting

Comment: I think the problem here is `nohop` doing string manipulation to make a system call.  there should be a big difference if `nohup` is passed a quoted string with a space, as opposed to a simple argument with a space, but no quotes.  It should be the difference inside `nohup` between `system( "java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -DUSER=Tim Tom ./app.jar" );` and `system( "java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -DUSER=\"Tim Tom\" ./app.jar");`

Comment: `nohup` doesn't do a `system` at all, it does `execvp` and passes all its arguments to that.  Word splitting in bash has already thwarted you before it gets that far.  So if you put `-DUSER='"Tim Tom"'` because the quotes there are just part of the string when that word splitting happens you are getting 2 arguments: `-DUSER="'Tim` and `Tom"'` and no amount of quoting will change that.

Comment: You can see that breaking up of the variables if you replace your `echo` with a `printf` that will show each argument separately, like doing `printf '%s\n' nohup $SC_CD` will show that `Tim` and `Tom` are different arguments to `nohup` regardless of the quoting you try to add

Comment: modified answer top-post style based on your comments

Comment: that nohup bash temp.sh works! thanks to all! :)